# PHP : check if num rows is zero

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to check if result returned by database is zero but it always falls to zero following is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['cust_id'])){
    $cust_id = $_POST['cust_id'];
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT send_stamp, message, time, status FROM `chat` WHERE cust_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $cust_id);

}
else if(isset($_POST['receiverid'])) {
    $receiverid = $_POST['receiverid'];
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT send_stamp, message, time, status FROM `chat` WHERE receiverid=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $receiverid);

}

if($stmt->execute()){
    $data  = array();
    if($stmt->num_rows ==0){
        $data[] = array(
           'message'=> 'No messages found',
           'status'=>0,
        );
    }
    else{
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $data[] = array(
                'message'=> $row['message'],
                'time'=> $row['time'],
                'status'=> $row['status'],
            );
        }   
    }
}
echo json_encode( $data);
```

Please help me to figure out this situation . Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this worked, havent tested it but can you var dump your num_rows

Comment: you can trace with `echo exit` which condition is execute

Comment: int(0)
[{"message":"No messages found","status":0}]null problem is  that i do have records against particular id

Comment: Have you checked that the query returns rows if you run it in phpMyAdmin or something like that

Comment: Which query is the problem? One, or both? Presumably the query doesn't return any results. Have you checked the correct query is running (and therefore that the correct POST values were sent)? Also, a basic question (but I've seen questions on here where OP had not actually checked this!) do the expected rows actually exist in the database you're connecting to? Are you connecting to the right instance of the database?

Comment: Check if it produced a resultset. You can detect whether the query produced a result set by checking if `mysqli_stmt_result_metadata()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @ADyson yeah i have checked i am connected to right db and cust_id does exist in the field i tried with receiverid  as well both fall to 0

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: $result = $stmt->result_metadata();
   $field = $result->fetch_field(); this gives me result   tihs is what i get stdClass Object
(
    [name] => send_stamp
    [orgname] => send_stamp
    [table] => chat
    [orgtable] => chat
    [def] => 
    [db] => dbname
    [catalog] => def
    [max_length] => 0
    [length] => 65535
    [charsetnr] => 8
    [flags] => 4113
    [type] => 252
    [decimals] => 0
)

Comment: check the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php - you have to store the result first before it will work. There is sample code on that page. If you don't do that then you have to loop manually through the rows to get the total.

Comment: @ADyson now that is working but below loop is not  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this one

execute query and get data into `result like  $result=$stmt->execute()` and that 
`result` compare in `if() condition like if($result)` and inside `if($result == 0)` so it give an result

```
$result=$stmt->execute();
if($result)
{  
    $data  = array();
    if($result ==0){
        $data[] = array(
               'message'=> 'No messages found',
               'status'=>0,
            );
    }
    else{

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $data[] = array(
               'message'=> $row['message'],
               'time'=> $row['time'],
               'status'=> $row['status'],
            );
        }   
    }
}
```

**OR**

also write `$result = $stmt->get_result();` after `if($stmt->execute())` and compare `if($result->num_rows ==0)` like this way